# toStream() doesn't work on Windowed KTable

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I want to write a small Kafka Streams app, that does a reduction on time windows of an input stream, does some mapping on the values and then sends the resulting change log of toStream() to another topic. 
With my code I am getting the following error at the toStream() operation:

```
Compilation failure
[ERROR] StreamFilter.java:[39,86] incompatible types: org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream<org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Windowed<java.lang.Integer>,filterExample.SensorMessage> cannot be converted to org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream<java.lang.Integer,filterExample.SensorMessage>
```

I have read somewhere that the default Serdes might be the problem, but so far, including them explicitly with `Consumed.with` has not solved the problem.

```
public static void runStreamFilter(String broker) throws Exception {
  final SensorMessageSerializer serializer = new SensorMessageSerializer();
  final SensorMessageDeserializer deserializer = new SensorMessageDeserializer();
  Properties props = new Properties();
  props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "stream-filter");
  props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, broker);
  props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.Integer().getClass());
  props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.serdeFrom(serializer, deserializer));

  final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

  final KStream<Integer, SensorMessage> input = builder.stream(KafkaConstants.TOPIC_IN, Consumed.with(Serdes.Integer(), Serdes.serdeFrom(serializer, deserializer)));
  final KStream<Integer, SensorMessage> output = input
    .filter((k,v) -> v.getValue() > 19) 
    .groupByKey(Grouped.with(Serdes.Integer(), Serdes.serdeFrom(serializer, deserializer)))
    .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMillis(500)))
    .reduce((aggValue, newValue) -> avgReducer(aggValue, newValue))
    .mapValues(value -> latencyMapper(value))
    .toStream();


  output.to(KafkaConstants.TOPIC_OUT);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

code 
`.windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofMillis(500))).reduce(..)`
returns `KTable<Windowed<K>, V>`.

in order to convert your result to `KStream<Integer, SensorMessage>`, you need to extract value from `Windowed` object, so you need to add the following code after `toStream()`:

`.map((key, value) -> KeyValue.pair(key.key(), value));`